# What is the purpose of cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 swapaccount=1

Tags: boot, 20.04, raspberrypi, kubernetes, cgroup

I am trying to setup a kubernetes cluster on a raspberry pi cluster using Ubuntu 20.04.3. In many online guides available, one of the steps is mentioned as follows:

Edit the `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` and add `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 swapaccount=1` at the end.

The above step is mentioned without any explanation. So, to check my current configuration (without applying the above boot config) I run `/proc/cgroups` which gives me the following output:

```
#subsys_name    hierarchy       num_cgroups     enabled
cpuset  8       1       1
cpu     4       43      1
cpuacct 4       43      1
blkio   7       43      1
memory  0       51      0
devices 10      43      1
freezer 3       2       1
net_cls 2       1       1
perf_event      5       1       1
net_prio        2       1       1
pids    6       48      1
rdma    9       1       1
```

Since swap needs to be disabled, I have checked it is already disabled. As such I have the following questions:

1. I believe in the output that `cpuset` is enabled since it has the value of 1 for the enabled column. Am I correct? If so, is explicitly setting `cgroup_enable=cpuset` necessary?
2. Since the value under enabled is 0 for `memory` I believe it is not enabled. Am I correct? If so, what does `cgroup_enable=memory` and `cgroup_memory=1` do? Why do I have to set both of them?
3. What is the purpose of setting `swapaccount=1`? Does it make sense to set it if swap is disabled anyway?

`cgroups` is a new topic to me and as such I would like to know better what each of the commands do instead of blindly copying them.

EDIT: I went through the kernel source code and noticed that nothing called `cgroup_memory` exists. Yes a function exists by that name but it binds to a command `cgroup.memory`. So, are all the online blogs talking about `cgroup_memory` just copied a typo as is?

Comment: Hi, i'm facing CPUSET missing in CGroup, were you able to solve it .?

Answer (score 1):

For 2, it seems that both flags are specific to the Raspberry Pi Linux kernel. The `cgroup_memory=1` is probably not necessary anymore, it is meant as a backwards compatibility flag. So as long as `cgroup_memory=0` is not present, `cgroup_enable=memory` should be good enough. [This comment](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1950#issuecomment-347481182) in the Raspberry Pi bug tracker is suggesting that.